# PHP regex match SKU (several patterns) in string

Tags: php, regex

There are names of records in which are mixed several types of SKU that may contains symbols, digits, etc.

Examples:

```
Name of product 67304-4200-52-21
67304-4200-52 Name of product
67304-4200 Name of product
38927/6437 Name of product
BKK1MBM06-02 Name of product
BKK1MBM06 Name of product
```

I need to preg_match (PHP) only SKU part with any symbols in any combinations.

So i wrote pattern:

```
/\d+\/\d+|\d+-?\d+-?\d+-?\d+|\bbkk.*\b/i
```

It works but not with [BKK*] SKU.

Is it way to combine all this types of SKU together in one pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern `\d+-?\d+-?\d+-?\d+` means that there should be at least 4 digits as all the hyphens are optional, but in the example data the part with the numbers have at least a single hyphen, and consist of 2, 3 or 4 parts.

You could repeat the part with the digits and hyphen 1 or more times, and instead of using `.*\b` use `\S*\b` to match optional non whitespace chars that will backtrack until the last word boundary.

Note that if you use another delimiter in php than `/`, you don't have to escape `\/`

Using a case insensitive match:

```
\b(?:\d+(?:-\d+)+|bkk\S*|\d+\/\d+)\b
```

**Explanation**

- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial word match
- `(?:` Non capture group for the alternatives

  - `\d+(?:-\d+)+` Match 1+ digits and repeat 1 or more times matching `-` and again 1+ digits (or use `{1,3}` instead of `+`)
  - `|` Or
  - `bkk\S*` Match `bkk` and optional non whitespace characters
  - `|` Or
  - `\d+\/\d+` Match 1+ digits `/` and 1+ digits
- `)` Close the non capture group
- `\b` A word boundary

See a [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/gCM3hS/1).

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
\d+(?:\d+(?:-?\d+){3}|\/\d+)|\b[bB][kK][kK][A-Za-z0-9-]*
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/2u8xdY/1).

**REGEX101 EXPLANATION**

```
1st Alternative \d+(?:\d+(?:-?\d+){3}|\/\d+)
\d matches a digit (equivalent to [0-9])
+ matches the previous token between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
Non-capturing group (?:\d+(?:-?\d+){3}|\/\d+)
1st Alternative \d+(?:-?\d+){3}
\d matches a digit (equivalent to [0-9])
+ matches the previous token between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
Non-capturing group (?:-?\d+){3}
{3} matches the previous token exactly 3 times
- matches the character - with index 4510 (2D16 or 558) literally (case sensitive)
? matches the previous token between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
\d matches a digit (equivalent to [0-9])
+ matches the previous token between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
2nd Alternative \/\d+
\/ matches the character / with index 4710 (2F16 or 578) literally (case sensitive)
\d matches a digit (equivalent to [0-9])
+ matches the previous token between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
2nd Alternative \b[bB][kK][kK][A-Za-z0-9-]*
\b assert position at a word boundary: (^\w|\w$|\W\w|\w\W)
Match a single character present in the list below [bB]
bB matches a single character in the list bB (case sensitive)
Match a single character present in the list below [kK]
kK matches a single character in the list kK (case sensitive)
Match a single character present in the list below [kK]
kK matches a single character in the list kK (case sensitive)
Match a single character present in the list below [A-Za-z0-9-]
* matches the previous token between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
A-Z matches a single character in the range between A (index 65) and Z (index 90) (case sensitive)
a-z matches a single character in the range between a (index 97) and z (index 122) (case sensitive)
0-9 matches a single character in the range between 0 (index 48) and 9 (index 57) (case sensitive)
- matches the character - with index 4510 (2D16 or 558) literally (case sensitive)
```